# UBO/SSBO dynamic indexing and bindless textures

Tags: opengl, glsl, nvidia

I have the following weird behavior in GLSL fragment shader: I am trying to pass a UBO (tried also SSBO) with an array of structures,where each structure looks like this:

```
 layout(location = 0)  uniform uint u_index;

 layout (std430, binding = 2) buffer MaterialBlock {
            u64vec4 data[];
 }material;
```

Here `u64vec4` holds the following values:

x - uint64_t bindless texture handle A

y - uint64_t bindless texture handle B

z - uint64_t bindless texture handle C

w - two uint32_t compressed into single uint64_t with some extra data.

And I have a code in fragment shader which looks like this( sorry,I can't put out the whole thing as this is commercial work,but this sample pins down the problem exactly:

```
     vec4 DoThing( sampler2D aTex, usampler2D cTex, float2 paramA, float4 paramB, float4 paramC)
     {    

         uint4 cTexData=  texelFetch(cTex, int2(paramA.x,paramA.y),0);
         vec4 color = vec4(0.0);
         for (int i= 0; i< int(cTexData.x); i++)
         {

           color += texelFetch(aTex, int2(paramB.x,paramB.y),0);
           //continue doing smth with color ..

          }
          //some more code..
          return color;
         }
       void main()
       {

         oColor = DoThing(sampler2D(material.data[u_index].x),usampler2D(material.data[u_index].z),..params...); 

       }
```

u_index - is a regular uniform which I pass to GPU before issuing a drawcall,and as you can see,it is used to index into u64vec4 array to retrieve related structure. But when I use it this fetch :

```
 uint4 cTexData=  texelFetch(cTex, int2(paramA.x,paramA.y),0);
```

fails.When I say "fails" that means that cTexData received wrong data which causes very long (sort of infinite loop) inside for().. which freezes the display for 20-30 seconds,which leads me to believe it samples from the garbage.

But if I index into SSBO or (UBO) with a constant value,something like this:

```
 void main()
   {

     oColor = DoThing(sampler2D(material.data[0].x),usampler2D(material.data[0].z),..params...); 
   }
```

Works! All the textures are samples correctly

I have been digging into OpenGL specs,and I can't find anything that could indicate that it is forbidden to index with uniform into UBO. But it just doesn't work. And I can't profile with Nvidia Nsight/Graphics because those don't support this GPU model yet,and renderDoc doesn't support ARB_bindless_texture

My system specs:  **Win10 Pro, Nvidia Quadro P2000, OpenGL 4.5**

PS: Before SSBO used also UBO with 140 layout,but decided to try SSBO to see if the issue maybe related to data layout.Nope.Same thing. On the client side the struct looks like this:

```
 struct MaterialData
 {
     uint64_t data[4];
 };
```

I also ran a check inside the shader code to make sure `u_index` has a value equal 0. It has. So I have no idea why dynamic indexing fails here.

UPDATE: Stumbled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40875564/opengl-bindless-textures-bind-to-uniform-sampler2d-array?rq=1) question,and I do use  `#extension GL_NV_gpu_shader5 : require`

**UPDATE 1:**

After several tests,it looks like NVIDIA driver implementation bug.
I will update once I receive a response to this issue from their driver team.